Meaning of でも in もちろん別のニュース番組でも
I am uncertain about the meaning of でも in もちろん別のニュース番組でも. I am pretty sure that this is an incomplete sentence but I am not sure what should come after でも. My intuition tells me that it should be もちろん別のニュース番組でもいい.

(Source: she is beautiful ch. 44)

In this sentence there is an inversion and the repetiton is omitted.
今やってるはずです←①
もちろん別のニュース番組でも〜①
でも←also
